Check if the function with domain of matrices is convex or not
Let $\mu,\delta\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma_0,\Sigma_1 \in Sym(n,\mathbb{R})$ (Set of all $n \times n$ real symmetric matrices) with $\Sigma_0\succcurlyeq 0,\Sigma_1\succcurlyeq 0$ (Positive semi-definite).
Notation: $||\cdot||-$ Eucleadian norm; $tr-$ trace of matrix; $M(n,\mathbb{R})-$ Set of all $n \times n$ real matrices.
I am trying to check if function $f$ defined as following is convex or not.
$$M(n,\mathbb{R})\ni H \mapsto f(H):=\underbrace{||H\mu+\delta||^2}_{(1)}+\underbrace{tr(H\Sigma_0H^T)}_{(2)}-\underbrace{2\ tr(\sqrt{\sqrt{\Sigma_1}H\Sigma_0 H^T\sqrt{\Sigma_1}})}_{(3)}\in \mathbb{R}$$
Observation: The terms $(1),(2),(3)$ are convex in $H$. So, $f$ is difference of convex functions.
I tried to take second derivative test to check but I was not able to take derivative of $(3)$.
If not possible to check in current premise, Will it help to restrict $\Sigma_0\succ 0,\Sigma_1\succ 0$?

Have you made computer simulations with (many pairs of) quasi-random symmetric matrices in order to be confident into your convexity conjecture ?

@JeanMarie I am not sure about convexity of the function. Sorry for causing confusion, I have edited the question.

"Will it help, etc." : I don't think so, unless you are looking for establishing strict convexity, which I don't think is your main concern.

A first test you can do is with diagonal matrices.

Can you please elaborate which test you are referring to? Thank you for the reply.

Testing for $A,B$ diagonal matrices with $\ge 0$ entries whether of not the following inequality $ f(tA+(1-t)B) \le t f(A) + (1-t) f(B)$ holds when $0 \le t \le 1$.

I doubt that this function is convex. For $n=1$, the function looks like
$$
f(x) = a x^2 + bx + c - d|x|
$$
with $a\ge 0$ and $d\ge0$.
If $d$ is not zero then this function is not convex:
$$
f(0) = c
$$
while for $t>0$
$$
\frac12 (f(+t)+ f(-t)) = a t^2 + c -t
$$
which is smaller than $f(0)$ for small values of $t$.
